# ExtJS(5.0): Hide/Destroy floating panel when its show by target gets hidden/destroyed

Tags: extjs

I will explain this problem with an example:
There are two panels P1 & P2(floating).I have assigned P1 as P2's showBy.Now when I destroy/hide P1 then ideally P2 must get hidden.But in this case P2 remains shown.
Is there any way that I can automatically hide this P2 when P1 gets hidden/destroyed.

Comment: `p1.on('destroy', p2.hide, p2);`...?

Answer (score 1):

I would do as Emissary suggested.

Add a listener to p1 to hide p2 when p1 gets destroyed or hidden.

```
p1.on('destroy', p2.hide, p2); 
p1.on('hide', p2.hide, p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a component that does exactly that: If you provide it with a "callingWindow" configuration, it will `showBy` the calling window, and if the calling window is closed, it also closes. If you don't provide it with a callingWindow config, it acts as a normal window:

```
Ext.define('MyComponent',{
    extend:'Ext.window.Window',
    initComponent:function() {
        var me = this,
            win = me.callingWindow;
        Ext.apply(me,{
            ...
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
        if(win) {
            win.on('beforeclose',function() {
                if(me) me.close();
            });
            me.showBy(win,'tl-tr');
        }
        else me.show();
    },
});
```

I use it like this:

```
xtype:'button'
handler:function(button) {
    Ext.create('MyComponent',{
        callingWindow:button.up('window')
    });
}
```